# Printing from a single list python

Tags: python, list, printing

EDIT:

```
 ['Station 5 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 6 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 7 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 8 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 9 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 10 average is less than 1.62644628099']
```

and

```
['Station 1 average is greater than 1.62644628099', 'Station 2 average is greater than 1.62644628099', 'Station 3 average is greater than 1.62644628099']
```

Is there a code that I can use to produce a result such that the output when printed looks like this

```
Station 5 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 6 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 7 average is less than 1.62644628099 
Station 8 average is less than 1.62644628099 
Station 9 average is less than 1.62644628099 
Station 10 average is less than 1.62644628099
```

and

```
Station 1 average is greater than 1.62644628099
Station 2 average is greater than 1.62644628099
Station 3 average is greater than 1.62644628099
```

Thanks for reading and any advice/help you can give.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function, which prints each element in a list with the `str` in between. Here I insert a new line between each element.

```
>>> lst1 = ['Station 5 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 6 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 7 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 8 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 9 average is less than 1.62644628099', 'Station 10 average is less than 1.62644628099']
>>> print '\n'.join(lst1)
Station 5 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 6 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 7 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 8 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 9 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 10 average is less than 1.62644628099
```

Same for the second list:

```
>>> lst2 = ['Station 1 average is greater than 1.62644628099', 'Station 2 average is greater than 1.62644628099', 'Station 3 average is greater than 1.62644628099']
>>> print '\n'.join(lst2)
Station 1 average is greater than 1.62644628099
Station 2 average is greater than 1.62644628099
Station 3 average is greater than 1.62644628099
```

---

Or, you can use a for-loop:

```
>>> for i in lst1:
...     print i
... 
Station 5 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 6 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 7 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 8 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 9 average is less than 1.62644628099
Station 10 average is less than 1.62644628099
```

---

```
>>> for i in lst2:
...     print i
... 
Station 1 average is greater than 1.62644628099
Station 2 average is greater than 1.62644628099
Station 3 average is greater than 1.62644628099
```

It's probably preferable to use the `join()` function, as it actually returns the result, so you can use it later in your code if you wish.

Comment: +1 but the `for` loop is preferable since you don't have to load a copy of the whole output into memory at once

Comment: @jamylak, the list is already in memory. Besides, `str.join()` accepts any *iterable* and so will work just as happily with a generator expression.

Comment: @Johnsyweb So you don't need to get into a habit of copying it again, or copying unnesecarily for any other data structures

Comment: @Johnsyweb there is, `str.join` creates a **new string** from `list1`

Comment: Oh! I see! Apologies, I completely misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Join the list members with the newline character.

```
print "\n".join(t)
print
print "\n".join(s)
```